# Can I combine asp.net 4.0 with classic asp, or can I convert classic asp to asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, asp-classic

I have a website made with Visual Studio 2010 / .net 4 / VB.

I really liked the layout of a FAQ system I found because it's simple, but it's in classic asp. So, obviously, I cannot include my master page layouts, but I guess that's okay.

But can I convert the FAQ system to asp.net, or is there some tool out there I can utilize?

If not, is it okay to have classic asp pages on a asp.net 4.0 website?

Any guidance would be truly appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would be better if you convert classic ASP pages to asp.net
the reason is obvious and same as why Microsoft introduced asp.net over ASP

you have more flexibility, simplicity, to build application and wider options of controls and options to go for and you have c#/Vb to clear the road for you.

And it would be quick to use a tool convert classic asp to asp.net, but that can lead you to many problems as even a single conversion escaped by tool would be hard to find and if you convert the code by yourself then for later, if any changes, you can easily do it as you know who is sitting where.

You can host classic asp pages in asp.net need to do some changes in IIS.

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/564/classic-asp-script-error-messages-no-longer-shown-in-web-browser-by-default/

but even that is not a good option as asp might be less supported by Microsoft in IIS.

Hope this would provide you with some help....

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to respond to my question.  The information you provided was excellent!  I will take your advice and convert the classic asp pages to asp.net pages.  Again, thank you for your time, and thank you for the information, Roh!