# combine classic asp with asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp-classic

I have a (huge) website written in classic asp. Now do I have to switch to vb.net (razor). Is there a way to combine those 2 till the switch is complete ?

Is there a way to let the application work with classic asp and vb.net ?

(I use webmatrix)(don't know if this is important information)
The reason I ask this is because the website contains more than

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I combine asp.net 4.0 with classic asp, or can I convert classic asp to asp.net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9782025/can-i-combine-asp-net-4-0-with-classic-asp-or-can-i-convert-classic-asp-to-asp)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you mix ASP and ASP.NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5755832/692942)

Comment: So many votes for an obvious duplicate question? This isn't the first time someone has asked this, just think about the initial influx of Classic ASP devs switching to ASP.Net when it was first released.

Comment: If you're going to start coding asp.net you really need Visual Studio.  (I think the free version is now called Community Edition, previous versions were called Visual Web Developer).  You'll find what you can do with Webmatrix is very limited.

Answer (score 4):

MSDN says you can run .asp and .aspx on the same server

> ASP and ASP.NET can both be used on the same Web server. That is, a
>   Web site or Web application within a site can contain both ASP.NET
>   pages and ASP pages. Because both ASP and ASP.NET pages can be
>   accessed from the same Web server, you are not required to port your
>   existing ASP pages over to ASP.NET-compatible pages. [...]

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973813.aspx

Comment: I use vb.net razor style is it possible with this (in webmatrix)